Holomorphic manifolds with an Einstein structure and non constant holomorphic sectional curvature
My  apology  in advance if this  question is obvious:
I  know that an  Einstein manifold  need  not  have  a  constant  sectional  curvature  example $\mathbb{C}P^n$.  But  this  space  has a  constant holomorphic sectional  curvature.
What  Einstein  manifold admit  a  holomorphic  structure whose  holomorphic  sectional  curvature is  not  constant?
Note:  I  admit that I  do not know the  answer  to the  above  question.  But after that I  know  an  answer the  next  step  would  be the  following: What is  a  manifold who  admite  Einstein  structure  and  also  holomorphic  structure  but  does  not  admit simultaneously  a  Riemannian metric  and  a  holomorphic  structure for  which the holomorphic  sectional  curvature would be  constant.  However  I  do  not include this  question to this post as original main question. Because I do not know even its  elementary  version, i.e, the main question.

A very simple example is $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$, but in general one should expect a very broad class (though not all) of Kahler manifolds to admit Einstein metrics. On the other hand, a metric has constant holomorphic sectional curvature only if it is covered by $\mathbb{CP}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{CH}^n$ (I.e., the complex space forms).

@GabeK  I guess the  reference is  Griffith&  Harris, yes?

It should definitely be there, but I don’t have a copy on hand to verify. The intuition that a broad class of metrics admit KE metrics is that it should be equivalent to some algebraic condition and I’ve heard experts say that “most” manifolds should satisfy it. However, this is not my area of expertise and there are certainly counterexamples, so I’m not sure how precise this is.

@GabeK  Yes  I  see, thank  you

Answer to expand on my comment:
A very simple example is $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$, but in general one should expect a very broad class (though not all) of Kahler manifolds to admit Einstein metrics. On the other hand, a metric has constant holomorphic sectional curvature only if it is covered by $\mathbb{CP}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{CH}^n$ (I.e., the complex space forms).
To give a non-trivial example with positive curvature, take your favorite Fano complex surface (a del Pezzo surface). There are 10 deformation families of these and Tian showed that a smooth Fano surface admits a Kähler–Einstein metric if and only if it is not the blow up of the complex projective plane in one or two points.
More generally, there is a deep result of Chen-Donaldson-Sun that a Fano variety admits a KE metric whenever it satisfies an algebraic condition called $K$-polystability, so to find examples for your question it suffices to find Fano manifolds which satisfy this condition but aren’t projective space.

Thank  you for  your  answer. I need  time  to  understand it.  BTW  by  cover  you mean universal  cover? What reference  for  the  first  paragraph?

I know (without proof) the similar  real case  the covering  by  spher, plane and hyperbolic space.

i know that $S^2\times S^2$ is covering  of itself so impossible  to be covered by the three space  you mentioned  so  I think  I got my  complete  answer  thanks  for  that. The  only remaining point:  Was the  reference  Griffith &Harris?
